# ACM stuff-Feeding Animals

Tags: algorithm

There is an ACM problem that I can hardly work out. If anyone can tell me how to deal with it? I'd  really appreciate it!

> ### Description
>
> To show your intelligence to the Lord, you must solve the problem as follows: 
>   Suppose there are m persons and n animals. A person can feed an animal peacefully if he/she is liked by the animal. 
>   Given a list of which person is liked by which animal, you are to determine whether all animals can be feeded peacefully on 
>   condition that every person can feed at most k animals.
>
> ### Input
>
> There will be multiple test cases. For each test case, the first line contains two integers m(1 <= m <= 100) and n(1 <= n <= 100), where m indicates the number of persons and n indicated the number of animals. The following lines contain the m * n 0-1 matrix indicating which person is liked by which animal. The ith person is liked by the jth animal if the jth element of the ith line is 1. The last line for each test case contains a single integer k, indicating the maximal number of animals one person can feed.
>
> ### Output
>
> For each test case,output "Yes" if all animals can be fed peacefully,"No" otherwise.
>
> ### Sample Input
>
> ```
> 2 8
> 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
> 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
> 2
> 7 2
> 1 1
> 1 1
> 1 1
> 1 1
> 1 1
> 1 1
> 1 1
> 2
> ```
>
> ### Sample Output
>
> ```
> No
> Yes
> ```

Comment: I have no idea why this question is closed as "too broad". This is a concrete question at hand, which is completely on topic and narrow enough. Unfortunately, it it unlikely to get enough attention to get reopened.

Comment: @Chuan Liu: The question as-is is too broad. What approaches have you tried so far, and what specific problem(s) did you encounter that you need help with? Also, questions that appear to say "please do my work for me" are usually frowned upon here and closed quickly.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved using **[max-flow problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem)**.

Create the following graph:

```
vertices:
V={s,t} U {persons} U {animals}
edges: 
E = { (s,p) | for each p in persons } U
    U {(p,a) | for each person liked by each animal} U 
    U {(a,t) | for each a in animal }
weight function on edges:
w(s,p) = k | for each p in person
w(p,a) = 1 for each p in persons and a in animals
w(a,t) = 1 for
graph:
G  = (V,E,w)
```

Now, you need to find the maximal integers flow from `s` to `t` on `G`. This can be solved using various algorithms like [Ford-Fulkerson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm)

The flow that reaches `t` is the number of animals fed, and the solution itself is given by the flow:

- If there is a flow (of weight 1) on an edge `(p,a)` - person `p` feeds animal `a`.
- No person feeds more than `k` animals, because the maximal flow that can reach a person `p` is `k`, so no more than `k` can exit `p`.